# Add slash to fa-video-camera

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am working on an app that is using the excellent font-awesome library.  We use the fa-microphone / fa-microphone-slash icons to control microphone muting.  I need something like fa-microphone-slash for a fa-video-camera, so that I can similarly control the webcam with semantics that are familiar to users.  Is there a way to make one from fa-video-camera by compositing FA classes?

Comment: There sure is. What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I would like to add a slash just like the microphone, but there is no slash icon to stack in the font-awesome icon library.  There is the ban icon, but no slash icon, which would be more intuitive to users.  I'd like to emulate this: [camera-slash-example](https://az545065.vo.msecnd.net/skype-faq-media/faq_content/skype/screenshots/fa11009/fa11009c.png).  I presently change the background and add a descriptive tooltip, but can't find something suitable to stack on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of piggybacking off of @LutonDatta's answer:

```css
.fa.fa-video-camera:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "/";
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-shadow: 3px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    line-height: 32px;
    left: 18%;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-2x"></i>
```

But I don't like that since I'm not sure how different browsers/OSs will render it (too lazy to check right now).

This solution is slightly better, but there's still a lot hard-coded. You might have to fiddle with this, and definitely if you have a different `box-sizing`

```css
.fa.fa-video-camera:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: .45em;
    top: 0;
    width: .2em;
    height: 1.7em;
    display: block;
    background: white;
    transform: rotate(36deg);
    border-right: .1em solid black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-2x"></i>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [stacked icons](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/):

```
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-ban fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

It's not exactly the same, but you could use that for the microphone as well. You can also change the opacity and color of the different icons.

Comment: I do change the background color and opacity.  I considered the ban icon, but that isn't as familiar to users as a simple slash, as is used for muting the microphone, and for cameras on Skype.  I'm looking for something like this: [camera-slash-example](https://az545065.vo.msecnd.net/skype-faq-media/faq_content/skype/screenshots/fa11009/fa11009c.png)

Comment: There's nothing available directly from font awesome right now. There's a pending issue for such an icon already (https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/3765). You can also submit your own with the slash as you like, I'm sure it would be approved if done well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom sign like "/" you can use css :after psuedo class.

```css
.fa.fa-video-camera:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "/";
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<i class="fa fa-video-camera fa-2x"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

using font awesome

```
<i class="fas fa-video-slash"></i>
```